# How do you pass args to gmaven groovy:execute?

Tags: groovy, parameters, maven, args, gmaven-plugin

I need to pass in some args to a groovy script that is executed via the gmaven. I can do this no problem if I execute the script directly on the command line like so:

printArgs.groovy...

```
for (a in this.args) {
  println("Argument: " + a)
}
```

command...

```
$groovy printArgs.groovy fe fi fo fum
```

output...

```
Argument: fee
Argument: fi
Argument: fo
Argument: fum
```

I can't see how to pass these args in to via the plugin though using mvn groovy:execute. Ideally, I want to set some default params in the plugin config, but be able to override them when i execute the command. It would be nice to be able to pass them as named-args too if possible.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/printArgs.groovy</source>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The plugin [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gmaven-generated/gmaven-plugin/execute-mojo.html) is a bit scarce (and also outdated). I see there is a 'properties' optional param but I don't think this is to be used for this purpose (or if it is, i can't get it to work!).

Cheers :)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I can answer my own question for reference sake...

Rather than pass in a list of args, it is possible to reference the project properties very simply as follows:

```
def someProp = project.properties['someProp']
```

In doing this, you can reference any properties defined in a  tag within the pom. Furthermore, you can define the properties in the same configuration tag as the groovy script.

Gmaven plugin config...

```
<configuration>
    <properties>
        <name>world</name>
    </properties>
    <source>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/bootstrap/helloWorld.groovy</source>
</configuration>
```

HelloWorld.groovy...

```
println("Hello $project.properties.name!")
// this also works
// println("Hello $project.properties['name']!")
```

Comment: FYI, you should load resources from the output directory, not their source location, so replace `${pom.basedir}` with `${project.build.outputDirectory}`